# strtok and it's usage

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm working on an assignment that requires string and file manipulation. I'm currently working on the string manipulation part and I'm trying to use strtok to separate lines in a file, split by a comma. However, I'm not sure how strtok works. I'm looking at the code below and don't quite understand why there is a NULL in the second strtok call, when NULL isn't even a string.

The code I'm running:

/*****************************************************************
 *
 * Purpose: Program to demonstrate the 'strtok' function.
 * Author:  M J Leslie
 * Date:    23-Apr-94
 *
 ****************************************************************/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
            /* Copy the constant into the memory
             * pinted to by 'test_string'       */
    char test_string[50]="string to split up";

    /* if 'test_string' is declared as below and the program will give a 
    * 'Segmentation fault' This is because test_string' is pointing
    * to a constant i.e. somethin that cant be changed.     

    char *test_string="string to split up";         */

    char *sub_string;

                /* Extract first string */
    printf("%s\n", strtok(test_string, " "));

                /* Extract remaining 
                 * strings      */
    while ( (sub_string=strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
    {
         printf("%s\n", sub_string);
    }
 }
 /*****************************************************************
 *
 * Program O/P will look like this...
 *
 *   string
 *   to
 *   split
 *   up
 *
 *****************************************************************/
```

Comment: What is the problem? Just read the description of the function.

Comment: `strtok` with `NULL` is to continue from where it left of last time you called it

Comment: To be fair, `strtok()` is an abomination and incredibly stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html):

> Each subsequent call, with a null pointer as the value of the first argument, starts searching from the saved pointer and behaves as described above.